# decay and distance with physically correct lighting in three.js

Tags: three.js

What does the `distance` setting mean in three.js in relation to physically based lighting?

For non physically based lighting the `distance` setting is a setting where the light's influence fades out linearly. Effectively

```
 lightAffect = 1 - min(1, distanceFromLight / distance)
```

I don't know physically based lighting well but it seems to me real lights don't have a distance setting, they just have a power output (lumens) and decay based on the atmosphere density. Three.js has both a `power` setting and a `decay` setting although it's not clear at all what `decay` should be set to as the docs effectively just say to set it to `2`.

What should I be setting `distance` for a physically based `PointLight` for example if I want physically based lighting?

```js
'use strict';

/* global dat */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});
  renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);
  camera.lookAt(0, 5, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  {
    const planeSize = 40;

    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: '#A86',
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }  {
    const cubeSize = 4;
    const cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
    const cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#8AC'});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
    mesh.position.set(cubeSize + 1, cubeSize / 2, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
  {
    const sphereRadius = 3;
    const sphereWidthDivisions = 32;
    const sphereHeightDivisions = 16;
    const sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(sphereRadius, sphereWidthDivisions, sphereHeightDivisions);
    const sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#CA8'});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
    mesh.position.set(-sphereRadius - 1, sphereRadius + 2, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    light.power = 800;
    light.distance = 20;
    light.position.set(0, 10, 5);
    scene.add(light);
    light.decay = 2;

    const helper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(light);
    scene.add(helper);

    const onChange = () => {
      helper.update();
      render();
    };
    setTimeout(onChange);
    window.onresize = onChange;

    const gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(light, 'distance', 0, 100).onChange(onChange);
    gui.add(light, 'decay', 0, 4).onChange(onChange);
    gui.add(light, 'power', 0, 3000).onChange(onChange);
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.2/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Not an answer: Units of distance are typically in meters. For a description of how `distance` affects lighting in your case, see the inline comments in `bsdfs.glsl`.

Comment: Reading the [linked paper page 32](https://seblagarde.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/course_notes_moving_frostbite_to_pbr_v32.pdf) it's apparently a kind of hack. The `distance` setting is there mostly so the 3D engine can know when the light is out of range and doesn't have to be considered to contribute so can be left out. It doesn't really give any guidance on what to set it do though. I sounds like it's basically "up to the artist" although I suppose you could calculate when the light with infinite distance is below some threshold and set distance to that or slightly more.

Comment: That said, If I understand three.js correctly three.js doesn't do any light management. All lights in the scene effect all objects that have materials affected by that type of light. As such `distance` can always be set to Infinity or some large number since setting it smaller has no meaning since it will not be culled?

Comment: Setting `distance` to zero is the same as infinity for basic lights. For physically-correct lights, you'd have to read the source to see what the ramifications are.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through three.js source and the paper it's linked to, at least as of r95 the distance setting should basically be `Infinity` for physically based lights.

In the paper they point out physically based lights shine to infinity but of course in a 3D engine that's no good. Most 3D engines need to compute the minimum number of lights per object drawn so a `lightDistance` setting was added, if the light is further way than `lightDistance` they can ignore the light. The problem is there will be sharp edge if they just stop using the light past `lightDistance` so they hacked in a falloff.

three.js copied that lightDistance and falloff setting from the paper but three.js does not cull lights from calculations when lights are far away so there seems to be no reason not to set `distance` to infinity AFAICT, at least as of r95.